# Datetime forma +zone FullCalendar is between NOW()

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, fullcalendar

I have to use fullcalendar check if there is an event in the current time and date, but does not work ... so what is wrong?

```
startdate VARCHAR
enddate VARCHAR 
ex. format = 2016-02-22T00:30:00+05:30
```

my query wrong:

```
SELECT * from calendar WHERE  startdate >= NOW() and enddate <= NOW()
```

Comment: Mysql is going to read that as a string, not a datetime. You should use a datetime and then format it as needed on output. Also once it is a datetime you can use the `between` function. `WHERE now() between startdate and enddate`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: I know but fullcalendar to function needs this format , I can not change fullcalendar for one query , thanks for the reply

Comment: Fullcalendar never talks to `mysql` (I think, based on tag description sounds like JS so client side) just format the string in PHP that you feed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysql now() function returns date with Y-m-d H:i:s format. Here you have to convert your start and end date to Y-m-d H:i:s format.

in php code convert your date to given format like

```
$start = new DateTime('2016-02-22T00:30:00+05:30');
$startdate = $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$end = new DateTime('2016-02-22T00:30:00+05:30');
$enddate = $end->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Now in mysql use this formatted dates

```
SELECT * from calendar WHERE  $startdate >= NOW() and $enddate <= NOW()
```